# Is there a one liner which can list public key fingerprints with authorized_keys as input?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

I'd like to audit the `authorized_keys` file on a number of servers and match them with known AWS key fingerprints.

Is there a one-liner which incorporates `ssh-keygen -lf` which will output the fingerprint of every key in an `authorized_keys` file in a nice list with line breaks?

Answer (score 5):

From [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/413231/how-to-get-all-fingerprints-for-ssh-authorized-keys2-file):

You can easily make it a function in your .bashrc:

```
function fingerprints() {
  local file="$1"
  while read l; do
    [[ -n $l && ${l###} = $l ]] && ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin <<<$l
  done < $file
}
```

and then do:

```
$ fingerprints .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
    find /path/to/keys/directory -type f -name "*.pub" -exec ssh-keygen -lf {} \; | awk '{print $2}'
```

Edit:
Whops, ok. get it now.

here you go:

```
    while read line; do ssh-keygen -lf "$line"; done < <(cat authorised_keys_file)
```

(if this file have one key per line)

Comment: thanks. I want to operate on the authorised_keys file, though, not individual .pub files

Comment: Ok, check if edited answer is the one liner you have been looking for.

Comment: thanks. please format your answer with any code, commands etc using the '{}' icon in the text editor

Comment: That doesn't work, `-f` expects a file name (and that file has to be a regular file as ssh-keygen opens and reads the file several times)

Comment: Use instead:

        `while read line; do echo "$line" > key.pub; ssh-keygen -lf key.pub ; rm key.pub; done < <(cat authorised_keys)`